Getting Access Token expired error for SharePoint url. The Auth Token present in url is expired
ERROR:

<span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_LabelMessage">The access token has expired. It's valid from '9/4/2024 6:13:00 AM' and to '9/4/2024 7:13:00 AM'.</span>

REASON FOR ERROR:

https://xxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xxxx_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxx&Translate=false&tempauth=v1.eyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxwMC04NjhkYjFmN2QxNWUiLCJhcHBfZGlzcGxheW5hbWUiOiJxyzxxxxyyyyy&ApiVersion=2.0

On parsing the AuthToken(tempauth) present in above URL using JWT parser getting expiry date (exp) :

"app_displayname": "xyz",
"aud": "00000003-0000-xxx-ce00-000000000000/xxxx-my.sharepoint.com@bf7cb6c1-xxx-4995-0000-2ac422f89f52",
"exp": "1725521823"

The Auth Token (tempauth) is valid for 1 hr. How to refresh this token?
How to refresh this expiry date present in url without reconstructing the new url?

That's the whole point of handing out temporary access tokens.

A context token is used only in the Context Token flow of the low-trust authorization system. When the SharePoint Add-in is launched in SharePoint, SharePoint requests that Azure ACS create a context token that SharePoint then passes on to the remote component of the SharePoint Add-in. The token is passed as a hidden form parameter called SPAppToken in a request from SharePoint for the start page of the remote component. The token is signed with a client secret known only to ACS and the SharePoint Add-in.
You could refer to following steps
https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/572464?language=en_US
